# React Axios interceptor and create not working

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to use Axios along with React. Since my backend service is using JWT I wrote an Axios request interceptor to add the bearer token every time there is a request made to the server. Below is the code snippet. But I am getting below error in the line ***axiosinstance.post***. If is use axios.post then the interceptor is not working. Could  you please let me know what is wrong and how to resolve the issue?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
    at request (APIUtils.js:9)
    at login (APIUtils.js:23)
    at Login.handleSubmit (login.js:36)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:362)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:411)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:466)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:480)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:612)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:637)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:743)
```

Code snippets
**axiosutilis.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

import { API_BASE_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN } from '../constants';

const axiosinstance = axios.create({
    timeout: 10000,
    params: {} // do not remove this, its added to add params later in the config
});

// Add a request interceptor
axiosinstance.interceptors.request.use(
   config => {
       if(localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
            config.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN))
       }
       config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
       return config;
   },
   error => {
       Promise.reject(error)
});


export default axiosinstance;
```

**APIUtils.js**

```
const request = (options) => {

    if(options.method === 'POST'){
       return axiosinstance.post(options.url, JSON.stringify(options.data))
        .then(response => 
            response.json().then(json => {
                if(!response.ok) {
                    return Promise.reject(json);
                }
                return json;
            })
        );
    }
};

export function login(loginRequest) {

    return request({
        url: "/api/auth/signin",
        method: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(loginRequest)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution works fine for me. Please find my code sandbox! In case it doesn't work let me know!

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-https-tylfu

Comment: I saw your example, everything is in one file. Can you put this into two files and check whether this is working for you?

Comment: updated my code sandbox! have a look @Debopam.. https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-rubin-i9uob

Comment: Thanks. somehow it worked today but it wasn't working yesterday :)

Comment: Hi @Debopam, can you mark this as resolved! It will be easier for people to find solutions down the line. Thanks!