# How to call the backend api in the front end react jsx file

Tags: reactjs, node.js, axios, dotenv

Currently im working on a CRUD application using React,Node,Express and Mysql and im new to it
the issue i'm facing is i'm having a session JWT token which is getting from backend and storing in the session.
but i'm not getting on how to pass it through all the request as a header to the backend to verify it
i'm having around 30-40 api link also which i'm calling directly as of now
eg:   const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/confirm/${Id}`, {
...data,
});

i know it's a bad practice to call api like this directly but i'm not getting on where to store them and call properly with passing the session id along with this to backend

i tried to put the api to .env file but didn't get how to pass the dynamic url variable through that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Axios interceptor and create not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58676853/react-axios-interceptor-and-create-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert here (it's my first answer in StackOverflow) but maybe I can point you to something from my experience using NextAuth and having a lot of problems myself to handle authentication properly.

I guess you're trying to make protected routes. I don't really know how to do that properly, but let me ask you something because if it fits your needs, it's way easier!

What I did was that I had in the frontend different interaction possibilities on whether user is authenticated or not. The only verification I did was on login, then store the token in the browser and serve different frontends for authenticated / not authenticated. In fact, not authenticated users (aka not a token in the browser) in my app only had access to login/signup page.
Once you are authenticated, you do the check in the client before the fetch.
Would that fit your needs?

I guess you still could handwrite the urls with queries, but to be hacked that way the person should have your other users session id. I don't think I'm offering here a full solution, as I said, I ended up using NextAuth.

I hope I was helpful at the least!

UPDATE: Seen the answer that is posted, I think it's doing kind of the same, probably better. But it's not responding to your question about server-side verification. But maybe I'm not fully understanding the code.

Comment: Thank you, yes you are correct i'm trying to do the protected routes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, declare axios config as :

```
axios.js

import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL, // Set your base URL in your .env file
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem('jwtToken'); // Get your JWT token from session storage or wherever you store it

    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }

    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default instance;
```

In your component :

```
import axios from './axios'; // Import the Axios instance

async function fetchData(Id, data) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`/confirm/${Id}`, data);
    // Handle the response
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors
  }
}
```

don't forget to init the env var in your env file:

```
REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:4000
```